# BitmapImage size restrictions in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bitmapimage

I'm making a Windows Phone 7 application which involves getting large images from the web and putting it in a `ScrollViewer` for the user to scroll through. I think I'm hitting a limitation of `BitmapImage`, though, as the image seems to get cut off at 2048 pixels in either height or width.

Is this a known limitation of Silverlight `BitmapImage` and is there some other class to use in this case to allow scrolling through the large images?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit of 2k x 2k. This is limitation and a workaround are described in the white paper "Creating High Performing Silverlight Applications for Windows Phone" http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=3a8636bf-185f-449a-a0ce-83502b9ec0ec

> Size Limitations: Since the Windows
>   Phone camera is 5 MP and the screen
>   resolution is smaller than on other
>   platforms, the limits for images that
>   can be processed are 2k x 2k pixels.
>   Anything larger than that will be
>   automatically sampled at a lower
>   resolution and the image will lose
>   some richness.  Processing Images
>   Larger than 2k x 2k There are
>   scenarios where you need to process
>   images larger than 2k x 2k, e.g. Photo
>   editor, or cropping images. In those
>   scenarios, you can process the images
>   that are larger than 2k x 2k into a
>   file, and then display a portion that
>   fits into 2K x 2K. You can use the
>   combination of WriteableBitmap with
>   LoadJpeg to do it.   Example #5 –
>   LoadingLargeImages

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Image Height="3000" Width="3000" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" />
    <Button Content="Load" Height="70" Width="152" Click="btnLoad_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
    Uri uri = new                                                                           Uri("LoadJpegSample;component/Test3k3k.JPG", UriKind.Relative);
    sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((int)this.image1.Width, (int)this.image1.Height);

    Extensions.LoadJpeg(wb, sri.Stream);
    this.image1.Source = wb;
}
```

> Things to Know When Using Larger than
>   2k x 2k Images:
>
> - It is significantly slower to display
> - Do NOT use it for animation or panning scenarios.

The Resize method of the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) can also be used for this task if no JPEG stream is available.

Comment: That's a good way to do it with local resources, but how would you suggest doing it with remote images from a URL?